# What is a desktop recorder with global shortcuts?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gtk3, screencast

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04. I searched on google hundreds of times and I couldn't find any solution for desktop recorder software.  There is the Kazam unstable version, but shortcut keys didn't work. I need a  stable desktop recorder with keyboard shortcuts. There are many options on windows for this. But on ubuntu, I couldn't find a desktop recorder with global keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: If your issue has been solved, could you please accept one of the answers instead of placing `[Solved]` in the title?

Answer (score 1):

**From Ubuntu Software Center**:

**RecordMyDesktop**   http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php

AND

**Istanbul Desktop Session Recorder** https://live.gnome.org/Istanbul

Comment: oh noo... these have no shortcuts... please I need shortcuts to pause when I record

Answer (score 0):

I didnt know that recordmydesktop has shortkeys.

to pause recording, just push

control + mod1 + p  (modal1 is generally left alt)

to stop recording

control + mod1 + s

that's all

you can check shortkeys for recordmydesktop here [click](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/rug/app_a.php)

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu 16.10 `recordmydesktop`**

The default `Ctrl + Alt + S` global shortcut to stop recording is already taken on Ubuntu by default by Keyboard > Shortcuts Windows > Toggle shaded state.

On the GUI version (`gtk-recordmydesktop`), 
I could not find how to change that setting, so I could only change the default Ubuntu shortcut to something else.

For the CLI version (`recordmydesktop`) you can use:

```
recordmydesktop --stop-shortcut Control+Mod1+x
```

as explained in `man recordmydesktop`.

I could not find a shortcut to start recording. Does not seem to exist according to: http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/rug/app_a.php